# medieval, Medieval, or either

Tags: capitalization

When I read about medieval history, the word is usually not capitalised, but sometimes it is. At the beginning of a sentence it always is, of course. I prefer to capitalise it in the middle of a sentence, but am I incorrect to do so, please?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can say :

- This is a medieval costume.
- In the Early Medieval Period (from the 6th century to the 10th century CE)

That should make the difference clear.

Historic time periodes like "Middle Age" "Stone-Age" ect....

Here is a chart of ["The Middle Ages"](http://slideplayer.com/slide/6008999/20/images/8/Middle+Ages-+Comes+from+the+term+Medieval,+which+is+Latin+for+middle+and+age.jpg)

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. Regards, Dave

Answer (score 1):

The OED records "medieval" as both adjective and noun, though in neither instance is the word "medieval" capitalised, except where it appears at the start of a sentence. **Hence I would adjudge that it is not a proper noun, and hence it should not be capitalised**.

> A. adj.
>    1. a. Of or relating to a period of time intervening between (periods designated as) ancient and modern; spec. of, relating to, or
>   characteristic of the Middle Ages. Also, of art, religion, etc.:
>   resembling or imitative of that of the Middle Ages.
>
> 1817   T. D. Fosbroke Brit. Monachism (ed. 2) I. Pref. p. vi   The
>   Author..professes to illustrate mediæval customs upon mediæval
>   principles.
>
> 1821   Gentleman's Mag. Nov. 426/1   Now the temporary Roman munitions
>   consisted of mere earth-work or wood-work, but the question here is,
>   was there such a thing as a work resembling a mediæval castle?
>
> 1848   B. Webb Sketches Continental Ecclesiol. 22   Open grills were
>   not uncommon in mediaeval times instead of close screens.
>
> 1876   W. Stubbs Early Plantagenets 6   Weapons drawn from the
>   storehouse of medieval English history.
>
> a1878   G. G. Scott Lect. Mediæval Archit. (1879) I. i. 7   Mediæval
>   architecture..being the last link of the mighty chain which had
>   stretched unbroken through nearly 4000 years.
>
> 1882   S. F. A. Caulfeild & B. C. Saward Dict. Needlework 344/1
>   Medieval embroidery, this is a modern Embroidery worked in the same
>   stitches as are used in Church Embroidery, [etc.].
>
> 1933   A. N. Whitehead Adventures of Ideas iv. 80   So far as concerns
>   Western Europe, the origin of the Mediaeval civilization must be dated
>   from the Emperor Augustus and the Journeys of St. Paul.
>
> 1948   Mind 57 535   Dr. Fung..does not, like many Chinese and most
>   Occidental expositors, make Confucius teach medieval Neo-Confucian
>   doctrine.
>
> 1975   J. Plamenatz K. Marx's Philos. Man iv. 102   We can say that
>   the Englishman and the Chinese, or the medieval European and the
>   modern European, are in fundamental respects alike in spite of the
>   differences between their cultures.
>
> 1989   Art Line Apr. 10/4   The most notable aspect of all the
>   drawings..was the diverse range of styles, ie, impressionist,
>   medieval, constructivist, abstract, realist, naive.
>
> B noun.  2. A person who lived in the Middle Ages. Also: a person
>   whose outlook or perspective is (regarded as) characteristic of or
>   resembles that of the Middle Ages.
>
> 1856   J. Ruskin Mod. Painters III. 193   The elements of their minds
>   by which..they are connected with the mediævals and moderns.
>
> 1894   C. H. H. Parry Stud. Great Composers: Palestrina 3   Though
>   their music was so limited the mediævals contrived to make some fine
>   effects with it.
>
> 1933   A. N. Whitehead Adventures of Ideas iv. 60   Lucretius, Cicero,
>   Virgil were mediaevals in their relation to Hellenic literature and
>   speculation.
>
> a1963   C. S. Lewis Discarded Image (1964) iii. 39   Yet all the while
>   she [sc. Nature] is, for the medievals, only a personification.
>
> 1974   A. L. Rowse in Listener 18 Apr. 494/3   The Elizabethans..were
>   medievals, like Chaucer's people, for the most part free and easy in
>   their sex-life.
>
> 1990   Canad. Jrnl. Linguistics 35 84   Medievals had a habit of
>   quoting standard authors from memory without giving references.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. Regards, Dave